# How can i fill a hole in this mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to close this hand mesh. I have tried fill, grid fill, and adding a new face. Nothing seems to work. I also tried extruding a new face and scaling it down to 0. Ideally, it can also be done with python. Thanks

[image: empty hand]

Comment: why not extrude, scale and merge at center?

Answer (score 0):

First off, its hard to tell from the picture but the last edge loop looks very thick, possibly indicating there is a double edge there? maybe check that but otherwise, i made a cylinder with the same amount of edges, the extra extruded edges and triangles. The grid fill seems to work fine if you have the right settings and right active edge.

[image]

Or am I missing somthing? is this not the desired effect?